# The Upsampling operation is not supported when convert Mxnet model to Onnx model

Tags: python, mxnet, onnx

When converting a Mxnet model which uses `mx.symbol.UpSampling` operation, there is an error occurred.

It seems that the Upsample operation in Onnx is not compatible with the UpSampling operation in Mxnet.

The error is:

`AttributeError: No conversion function registered for op type UpSampling yet.`

Answer (score 0):

The UpSampling operator is not available yet. See this PR for tracking progress: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/14042